# Thinkpad T430, Ubuntu 18.04, No sound on startup sometimes

Tags: sound

Sometimes I have sound when I start, sometimes I don't. Rebooting has always fixed it so far...

Lenovo Thinkpad T430, Ubuntu Studio 18.04. No sound from headphones or speakers. Sound buttons on top panel don't do anything.

I'd kinda like to have some tips on troubleshooting this from the terminal. 'aprops' suggestions, i.e.

Comment: And you have checked the log files?

Comment: I have this sometimes, usually restarting alsa fixes it.